# ng-if and ng-show in my Ionic application, neither works

Tags: html, angularjs, ionic-framework

The html code goes something like this:

```
<div ng-if="name=='John'">
<div class="item item-avatar"> <img ng-src="john.jpg"></div>
</div>
<div ng-if="name=='Margaret'"
<div class="item item-avatar"> <img ng-src="margaret.jpg"></div>
</div>
```

Instead of ng-if, I've tried using ng-show as well. Neither worked. Both John as well as Margaret showed on the page no matter which I used. I tried with ng-switch also.

The variable 'name' I initialized earlier on the same HTML file as:

```
<a class="item item-avatar item-icon-right" ng-init="name = 'John'" href = "#/Page3"></a>
```

Clicking on the above line leads to Page3 where I need to display either John or Margaret depending on the value of 'name'.

Is the syntax wrong or something, because that could be very well possible. I'm new to Ionic and AngularJS.

Comment: Does seem to work here http://jsfiddle.net/2y36mjcw/

Comment: Yeah... I must have done something wrong somewhere else.. Thanks! :)

Comment: Maybe a dumb question, but do you have the `angular` script included?

Comment: for Ionic, I use do: `<div *ngIf="ready">ready to go</div>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed you [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/o8QRg50SWZunSfnfmaMc?p=preview) - now it should be working.

Bug #1: ng-init is for initialization not to set values at runtime -> use ng-click instead

Bug #2: You use the same controller for all pages but for each page a new controller will be initialized, which resets the 'name' property

I implemented a setName function to set the name in the rootscope and to go to page3. In a correct implementation you should pass the name as a $stateparam to the new state/page. But for that please have a look at the ui-router documentation.

```
  $scope.setName = function(name) {
    console.log(name);
    $rootScope.name = name;
    $state.go('Page3');
  };
```

Comment: o_0 Ok.. I clearly have a long way to go :) Thanks! I'll check it out and see if it works! :D

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<div ng-show="name=='John'" ng-init="name = 'John'">
  <div class="item item-avatar"> John</div>
</div>
<div ng-show="name=='Margaret'"
  <div class="item item-avatar"> Margaret</div>
</div>
```

Works for me. I just change ng-if to ng-show - which will shows div content when true and hide it otherwise. I also use ng-init inside a div.

Comment: I tried ng-show. It doesn't work. Never mind I must have made some mistake somewhere else! Thanks! :)

Comment: Well, if those pages have different controller, then 'name' variable should be a rootscope - $rootscope.name, instead of $scope.name.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you started Angular? Did you set the ng-app directive?
It would help if you could provide a working example if you have other problems.

```js
angular.module('app', []);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-init="name = 'John'">
  <button type="button" ng-click="name='John'">John</button>
  <button type="button" ng-click="name='Margaret'">Margaret</button>

  <div ng-if="name=='John'">
      This is John
  </div>
  <div ng-if="name=='Margaret'">
    This is Margaret
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I set ng-app. I hadn't included that <script> thing earlier. Now I added that too. It still doesn't work. But my syntax isn't wrong is it?

Comment: Then you have to post your complete code ;-). I can't see a syntax error in the part you posted.

Comment: Did you initialize angular module `angular.module('app', []);` ? Do you see any errors in the browser console?

Comment: Yeah :D I did. No errors in the console. I have around 5-6 pages in the app and they all load. There's just this error. It's been driving me insane for a day.

Comment: Please provide a plunker with your code so we can help you

Comment: What is Plunker supposed to be?

Comment: Google is your friend! http://plnkr.co/edit/?p=catalogue - You can provide  part of your code here so others can check it and give you support